# Preserving line feeds in textarea

Tags: javascript, textarea

I'm looking to create an email template from a textare and that can be displayed in a div as well as sent over mailto. Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z6rpY/).

The HTML is pretty simple:

```
<textarea id="TheTextInput" rows="5"></textarea>
<input type="button" id="TheButton" value="click" />
<div id="TheOutput"></div>
```

and the javascript that I'm currently trying out looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#TheButton').click(PutTextIntoDiv);
});

function PutTextIntoDiv() {
    var TheText = encodeURIComponent($('#TheTextInput').val());
    $('#TheOutput').text(TheText);
}
```

Here's the output for now:

[image]

As you can see, the encoding and decoding is not working because the line feeds aren't preserved. What do I need to change?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I suppose you need to decode the string with `decodeURIComponent()`

```
function PutTextIntoDiv() {
    var TheText = encodeURIComponent($('#TheTextInput').val());
    $('#TheOutput').text(decodeURIComponent(TheText));
}
```

and replace `<div>` with `<pre>` in your HTML:

```
<pre id="TheOutput"></pre>
```

Another option if you want to have explicit `<br>` tags (or whatever):

```
var brText = TheText.replace(/%0A/g,"<br/>");
```

Comment: @frenchie: It does work. A `div` won't show the line breaks, but they're there. Visible line breaks in HTML are accomplished with `<br>`. [Here's your demo](http://jsfiddle.net/z6rpY/2/) using a `pre` element instead.

Comment: Ok!!!! Thanks for the answer! Here's the updated jsFiddle for those looking for the code: http://jsfiddle.net/z6rpY/4/

Comment: Sorry for the intromission... I usually don't edit answers like that, but I thought this one would benefit from my changes. Fell free to rollback if you didn't like them.

Comment: No problem, good clarification. (As for the <br/>... i prefer to end all tags like in xml, but that's perhaps just me.)

Comment: @bfavaretto: I rolled back to the initial answer AND added yours as well. I feel that adding decodeURIComponent() and using <pre> instead of <div> is the answer I was looking for and that your answer also works if changing to <pre> isn't an option. So now, both options are on the answer.

Comment: Sorry for the br/, I didn't notice I changed that! The intent was to just use backticks to escape the tags!